# Import project in target msbuild

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have problem with import project in Target - MSBuild. I want one general .target and connect with other. For example:

general.targets:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
        <Target Name="SetCoreTargetConfig" AfterTargets="Assemble">
            <Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)CI.targets" Condition="'$(SOPWCFInstance)' = 'CI'"/>
            <Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)DEV.targets" Condition="'$(SOPWCFInstance)' = 'DEV'"/> 
        </Target>
    </Project>

and CI/DEV.targets:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <ItemGroup>
    <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
        <ProjectReference Include="..\CI.Core\CI.Core.csproj">
            <Project>{2335596F-023E-4522-9F3E-A6D312512B}</Project>
            <Name>CI.Core</Name>
        </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
        <Warning Text="Load reference CI.Core"/>
    </Project>
```

I get an error after build project with "The import task was not found". Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

`Import` is not a task, hence the error, and cannot be used inside a target. The `Import` element must be used top level inside a project file (more precisely, inside the `Project` element).

You may want to read [How MSBuild builds projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2022), especially the "Evaluation Phase" section.

In (sloppy) short: `Import` helps structuring the files, once MSBuild has read the complete project (throughout multiple imports), it starts running targets. (You can also use `MSBuild.exe -preprocess` to get a look at that final all-imported file).

In your case, it could simply be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)CI.targets" Condition="'$(SOPWCFInstance)' = 'CI'"/>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)DEV.targets" Condition="'$(SOPWCFInstance)' = 'DEV'"/> 

    <Target Name="SetCoreTargetConfig" AfterTargets="Assemble">
    </Target>
</Project>
```

But I'm not sure, since I don't know the expected behaviour in your case.

Comment: I changed import tag to copy tag and it works fine for me,but sometimes I have to clean cs.proj because target won't activate when switching to different reference. Any ideas?

Comment: @MateuszBiałas "I changed _import tag_ to _copy tag_" - I'm sorry, but tahat doesn't make any sense, in this context, to me. `<Import>` and `<Copy>` do totally different things.

Comment: I have copy tags with conditions and I copy all content to the target .targets file.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you need to (heavily) update your original question (or ask a new one).